# Asset Catalog Compiler Error

Tags: xcode, ios7

I'm not sure what I did to get this error in Xcode 5:

"None of the input catalogs contained a matching app icon set named "AppIcon"".

My app was building fine - then my machine locked up tighter than the arctic - don't know why - and now I get this error.

(There was an existing answer to this same question - but I couldn't quite understand it.  Sorry)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For me the solution was [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57504566/2537455) (given I had no .psd as .png, etc.).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I had this problem when I accidentally saved a .psd as a .png. Converting the image to an actual png instead of a Photoshop file fixed it for me.

Comment: This is such a fail and happens more often than I care to admit.

Comment: Just did this too - Photoshop needs to give dominance to the .xxx file extension over their drop-down, or I need to stop being stupid.

Comment: God bless Stack Overflow! I can't imagine how many hours I would've wasted ten years ago, because of this stupid mistake.

Comment: For me the solution was this (given I had no .psd as .png, etc.): https://stackoverflow.com/a/57504566/2537455

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so I haven;t had an answer overnight yet - so I prodded around myself - went into the general tab - App Icons section - and clicked 'Use AppIcon' button instead of 'Don't use asset calalogues'.

That fixed it - compiler error disappeared.

Not exactly sure what it all means frankly.  More docs to plod through, I suppose.

Anyway hopefully this may help someone else.

Thanks.

Comment: The opposite worked for me : something (perhaps upgrading to Xcode 8.3?) set 'App Icon Sources' to "AppIcon" and changing it back to "Don't use asset catalogues" fixed it for me.  Thanks for posting your answer.

Comment: Oh - wait - but now I have some kind of weird default icon ... this didn't really fix it for me after all ... but by clicking the little arrow and going into the asset catalogue I can see that there are , of course , new icon sizes required - I bet I need to create them and then it will fix it.

Answer (score 6):

If you changed the deployment target to some other version. The dependencies will be changed. In my case i changed from iOS 6 to 7 by mistake. changing back made it error free.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and I had accidentally deleted the asset catalog for my app icons.  Fortunately, I had a backup version. To fix it, I went to the Images.xcassets folder within my project folder and   copied the AppIcon.appiconset folder from my backup project - worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple Solution:**

I was stuck in this issue and after reading "**@Michael Enriquez**" post, I realized that this problem occurred due to wrong **formatted image resource**, I was worried how to check which file I saved incorrectly if I have so many image resources.
So I just used a software named **ImageOptim** from **AppStore** which I normally use for reducing image sizes, so I **dragged** all the images to **ImageOptim** and I realized the wrong file, **ImageOptim** showed a **cross sign** on the wrong formatted image, then I changed that specific image to png and my problem is solved. I hope this solution will help you. Have a look at the snapshot below:

[image]

Comment: I just happened to have ImageOptim open at the time of reading this answer so figured I'd give it a try. Worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: Best solution ;)

Comment: You can also do it in terminal:
`grep -rL "PNG" --include \*.png . `

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and tried several solutions but in the end it was a bad image file as well.  I finally identified the troublemaker by deleting all the images and then re-adding them one by one until it wouldn't compile anymore.  When I tried to open that file in Photoshop it gave me the following error message:

"Could not complete your request because the file-format module cannot parse the file."

Answer (score 0):

I had imported all the images from a folder into images.xcassets at once then started getting build failed.I tried deleting one image set at a time and build (⌘b) until I get the project build properly and understood one image set causing issue. Then continued deleting one image from that image set and build (⌘b) until I get build succeeded and **found the culprit!**. Because a different format file had been renamed to PNG.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this amoying error and besides deleting a wrongly included .psd file I´ve also RMC over the .xcodeproject/Show Package Contents and deleted the .xcworkspace file.

Hope this help others too.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I added multiple time AppIcon set in Images.xcassets. I found that selected AppIcon set in Target/General/App Icons and Launch Images/AppIcon is different than the Target/Build Setting/Asset Catalog Compiler-Option/Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name. So that make sure AppIcon/LaunchImage set name must be same.

Answer (score 0):

For me the quickest fix was to (first copy and make sure you have a backup of images) delete all files within Images.xcassets. Then go to "Editor" on top menu and click "New Image Set" all the way to "New OS X Icon" below that just to be safe. After this copy n paste back the images with the empty "New etc." still in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue, in my experience it caused by :

1. wrongly formatted file -> for example you have jpeg file and you want to convert it to png by renaming its name. You should converted or exported it properly by using image editing software, for example photoshop.
2. Wrong size -> in my case i created an icon 72 px X 72 px but when i imported it became 73 px X 73 px, it caused by adobe illustrator clipping system. You should set it's size to fit the app icon requirement correctly.

note : for wrong size you need to place your art board in a clear coordinate, for example 1000 px, 200 px, i get it right by using top left anchor.

Answer (score 0):

for my case i faced same problem ,when I updated Xcode to 9.2 from 8.3 ,

i just upgrade the Deployment target in both TARGETS and PROJECT section to minimum iOS 11.0
from Xcode side panel , and solved

Answer (score 0):

There is one mole in your images. Find him and remove it. Try removing all images then add few images and try compile again. Do this until you find out the bad image.